# Putting progress bar inside edit text which will launch after user has entered something

Tags: android

I have a email address field which I need to check for availability with the server. I have the webservice to perform this test as an async task. While this check is going on, I want the user to fill in other details but I want a progress indicator to show that processing is going on in the email field.

I was hoping to make show a progress bar indicator inside the EditText field itself (possibly in the right corner of EditText). Is it possible?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the relevant code for this, and explain what you've tried so far, and how/why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a progressBar with the same properties of EditText you defined in XML.Put both inside one RelativeLayout and make that progressbar centerInPArent..And Note that the edittext should fill_parent both in height and width..It will appear as if progress is in EditText...And set the visibility gone of progress whereever applicable

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/colorStriptext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height=fill_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make visible and invisible any view like this

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setVisibility(View.View.INVISIBLE);
```

What you need to do is make edit text invisible and ProgressBar visible in onPreExecute.Do the reverse in onPostExecute method.

Comment: i want both EditText and ProgressBar to be visible