# How to propagate focus to a parent view

Tags: android, focus

I have a Layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/progressBar1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

where `border_selector` is a `selector` for the parent layout. The inner child `AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't have any background or border. So, on this `AutoCompleteTextView` focus I want to make the Parent also to get focus so that the selector works.

I tried this(It didn't work. Even if it works, this isn't a good solution I suppose):

```
    autoComplete.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(hasFocus){
                parent.requestFocus();
            }else{
                parent.clearFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to make the layout seem selected when the view has focus. Instead of using a selector programmatically change the background of the layout when it gets focus.

But you should know that this isn't expected behavior for Android and you should most likely leave it as it is :)

**EDIT:**

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/progressBar1"
```

remove this line, this way the progressbar will appear to be inside the textview see here for reference: [Putting progress bar inside edit text which will launch after user has entered something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624664/putting-progress-bar-inside-edit-text-which-will-launch-after-user-has-entered-s)

Comment: `isn't expected behavior` Yeah but my layout is to show a progressbar on the right side of the autocomplete(to show when getting data) so that it looks like its inside the autocomplete itself.